# Use an existing microservice architecture with kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I've an existing microservice architecture that uses Netflix Eureka and zuul services,

I've deployed a pod that successfully registers on the discover server but when I hit the API it gives a timeout, what I can think is that while registering on the Discovery server the container IP is given because of which it is not accessible.

Is there a way to either map the correct address or redirect the call to the proper URL looking for a easy way, as this needs to be done on multiple services

Comment: How did you set up your cluster and what did you do inside it? Please provide reproduction steps. Where exactly is the problem and what did you try?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be rethinking your design in Kubernetes way!  Your Eureka(service discovery), Zuul server (API gateway/ Loadbalancer) are really extra services that you really don't need in the Kubernetes platform.

For Service discovery and load-balancing, you can use **Services** in Kubernetes.
From Kubernetes documentation:

> An abstract way to expose an application running on a set of Pods as a
> network service. With Kubernetes, you don't need to modify your
> application to use an unfamiliar service discovery mechanism. Kubernetes gives Pods their own IP addresses and a single DNS name for a set of Pods and can load-balance across them.

And for API gateway, you can think about **Ingress** in Kubernetes.
There are different implementations for Ingress Controllers for Kubernetes. I'm using Ambassador API gateway implementation.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/

Comment: Thanks for your help, I came across an article with the possible ways https://www.magalix.com/blog/kubernetes-patterns-the-service-discovery-pattern, as we already have an existing architecture is using Ingress to move services slowly to Kubernetes will be the best approach ? then when all service is moved then remove the extra discovery and API gateway